# Angular: Is sharing a Controller between views a sign that Service is needed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an Angular app that includes three (potential) initial views for users who are not currently signed in:

- `intro.html`: Gives user option to 'Sign in' or 'Register'
- `register.html`: New user registration form
- `login.html`: Existing user login form

I currently have one service, `auth.service.js` that connects to [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/):

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('authService', authService);

authService.$inject = ['$firebaseAuth'];

function authService($firebaseAuth) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://[MY-FIREBASE].firebaseio.com');
  return $firebaseAuth(ref);
}
```

I then have one controller, `login.controller.js`, that depends on `authService` to create user accounts, login users, connect to Facebook, etc. Here is a portion of that controller:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

RegisterController.$inject = ['authService','$location'];

function RegisterController(authService,$location) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.createUser = function() {
    vm.mismatch = false;

    if (vm.password === vm.confirm) {

      authService.$createUser({
        email: vm.email,
        password: vm.password
      }).then(function(userData) {
        $location.path('/people');
      }).catch(function(error) {
        alert(error);
      });
    } else {
      vm.mismatch = true;
      vm.mismatchMessage = 'Password and confirmation must match';
    }
  };

  // login with Facebook
  vm.connectFacebook = function() {

    authService.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook").then(function(authData) {
      $location.path('/places');
    }).catch(function(error) {
      alert("Authentication failed:", error);
    });
  };
...
}
```

I share this controller between my three 'intro/register/login' views, but this feels 'wrong' to me. Would moving my `createUser`, `connectFacebook`, and similar logic into my `auth.service.js` file and then creating 'skinnier' controllers for each view which depend on `authService` be a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their dev guide (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller):

> Using Controllers Correctly
>
> In general, a Controller shouldn't try to do too much. It should contain only the business logic needed for a single view.
>
> The most common way to keep Controllers slim is by encapsulating work that doesn't belong to controllers into services and then using these services in Controllers via dependency injection. This is discussed in the Dependency Injection Services sections of this guide.

So, the short answer is, go ahead and split them into different controllers. If you need to share data between them, you should use a service to do so.